# hibernate criteria API: filtering by subset

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, criteria-api

I have a class which contains a Set of Bs.

I'd like to make an Hibernate Criteria to get all A's for which the set of Bs is a superset of some given set.

To make an example:

let's say we have three objects of type A

a1, which has the set of Bs = [b1, b2, b3]
a2, with the set = [b3, b4, b5]
a3, with the set = [b3, b5]

suppose I want to get all A's such that it's set contains [b3,b5].
Then the result would be a2 and a3

I hope I made myself clear. Thanks in advance!
Manuel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it like this. It was hard to figure out that this worked, but It's quite simple once you see it.

```
        B[] subset = new B[] {b3, b5};
        DetachedCriteria.forClass(A.class).createAlias("bs", "b");

        for (B b : subset) {
            criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("b.id", b.getId()));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this criteria would do the trick (assuming the property on `A` that contains the set of `B` entities is called `bs`):

```
DetachedCriteria.forClass(A.class).add(Restrictions.and(
    Restrictions.in("bs", new B[] { b3, b5 }),
    Restrictions.notIn("bs", DetachedCriteria.forClass(B.class).add(
        Restrictions.notIn("this", new B[] { b3, b5 }))
    )
));
```

Probably not very efficient, though.

Comment: this doesn't work. It would also return a1 in the example, because a1 has a 'b' that is in { b3, b5 }.

Comment: aha.  sorry to have missed that detail.  see the edit i just made.  i'm not sure if "this" works in Criteria queries (slips my mind at the moment), but if not, then you can use the entity's id.

Answer (score 0):

Before thinking of Criteria, you need to pencil raw SQL first.

You could do this in SQL the following way (assuming there is a table `AB` joining records between `A` and `B` where `fk_A` points to `id` in `A` and `fk_B` points to `id` in `B`):

```
SELECT fk_A, count(fk_B) FROM AB
   WHERE fk_B IN (b3, b5)
   GROUP BY fk_A 
   HAVING count(fk_B) = 2
```

This way you will not get "incomplete" entries from `A` as `HAVING count(fk_B)` statement filters them. Needless to say, you will have to replace `2` with relevant number if the amount of Bs is different.

Next goes the hard bit of converting this into Criteria :) Some pseudo (read: untested) code:

```
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(A.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.in("fk_B", new String[] {b3, b5}));

ProjectionList projectionList = Projections.projectionList();
projectionList.add(Projections.count("fk_B"));
projectionList.add(Projections.groupProperty("fk_A"));
criteria.setProjection(projectionList);
```

As you can see, this Criteria still misses `HAVING` bit in it. Unfortunately, `HAVING` is [not yet supported](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-1043) in Criteria API. You should, however, get the list of results and [counts](http://www.kodejava.org/examples/397.html) and ignore those where count is less than required.